# Does 換骨奪胎 have negative connotation?

Tags: expressions, idioms, yoji-jukugo

In the book [ロボット学論集 by 瀬名 秀明](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E7%80%AC%E5%90%8D%E7%A7%80%E6%98%8E%E3%83%AD%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E5%AD%A6%E8%AB%96%E9%9B%86-%E7%80%AC%E5%90%8D-%E7%A7%80%E6%98%8E/dp/4326101857), I saw this sentence (not exact since I'm solely depending on my memory)

> 2004 年公開の映画 "I, Robot" は，Isaac Asimov の同名の小説を換骨奪胎した別物である．

I looked at several online dictionaries, all of which didn't seem to me that the expression doesn't have negative sense by definition. However this book makes me feel like the author implies negative sense. Can anyone show references that define the term more clearly regarding this aspect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are several definitions:

> （骨を取りかえ、胎（子の宿る所）を自分のものとする意）先人の詩文などの表現法を借りながら趣旨に変化を試みて、独自の作品を作りあげる技法。誤用されて、他の作品の焼き直しの意にいうことがある。換骨。 (日本国語大辞典)
>
> 先人の詩文の作意や形式を生かしながら、新しい工夫を加えて独自の作品にすること。⇒骨を取りかえ、胎（=子宮）をわが物として使う意から。「焼き直し」の意に使うのは誤用。（明鏡国語辞典）
>
> 注釈：骨を取り換え、胎（子宮）を奪い取って自分のものにするの意から。なお俗に誤って、単なる焼き直し、模倣の意に用いられることがある。（故事ことわざ辞典）
>
> 注釈：骨を取り換え、胎児を奪うの意から。本来は、先人の作品をよりどころとすることを言ったもので、「焼き直し」のような悪い意味ではなかった。（四字熟語辞典）
>
> △の例文では、従来のものに少し手を加えて新しい作品であるかのように見せる意で用いている。本来なら、「何の新撰味もない作風」に対しては「模倣」「二番煎じ」「焼き直し」などというべきで「換骨脱退」を使うのは誤りだが、最近では許容されている。（略）「換骨脱退」は盗作のことではない。もっとも、俗には、盗作に近い焼き直しの意で使われることもある。（言葉の作法辞典）

I chose these because in addition to the normal, positive sense, they also note a negative sense. This negative sense is described as a mistake and is colloquial.

If you need any help understanding these citations, just ask.

Comment: these are really helpful (with source being noted). And with this being clarified, in my particular case, the author's opinion is unclear from the context, but because he repeated the similar expressions, he might have used it as primary meaning.